# SAM template - Sending SQS item to existing Java service

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless

We currently have
a requirement of:

APIEndPoint ---> aws Lambda ------>aws SQS  ----->   Java_service

where *APIEndPoint*, *Lambda* & *AWS_SQS* are serverless functionality(new) that needs to be wired with existing *Java_service* (not a serverless functionality).

Lambda is a NodeJS runtime

SQS name is `MyQueue`(say)

---

Instead of Java_service(above), If it was another NodeJS lambda function(say `sqsHandler`),like:

APIendPoint ---> aws Lambda ------>aws SQS  ----->   aws Lambda 2

then the template would be:

```
functions:
   sqsHandlFunc:
     handler: handler.sqsHandler
     events:
       - sqs:
          arn:
             Fn:GetAtt:
                 - MyQueue
                 - Arn
             batchSize: 1
```

---

What should be the SAM template wiring, if the handler(`sqsHandlFunc`) is wiring awsSQS to a  java service(non serverless)? java service(springboot app) is available through REST api

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to set that up through a SAM template. You will instead need to make the Java service poll the SQS queue using the [AWS Java SDK for SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html), specifically receiveMessage [(see the receiveMessage section in this example)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs-messages.html)